# JQuery blur and hide causing over-firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using  jQuery v1.11.2 and have created a basic JSFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/k1g3upbv/).  It does not show up very well in JSFiddle because my project also uses twitter Bootstrap.  I also rushed through the JSFiddle a bit because I had to remove code to simplify (e.g. removing my AJAX calls)... so please just use the JSFiddle code as a guide.

What ***should*** happen :

- User enters ID to check
- AJAX call is made when *focus && ID > 10* or *blur && id>10*
- The AJAX call ends by hiding the input field and displaying a clear button
- Upon clicking the clear button, the field re-appears and result and input boxes silently cleared

What ***does*** happen :

- User enters ID to check
- AJAX call is made when *focus && ID > 10* or *blur && id>10*
- The AJAX call ends by hiding the input field and displaying a clear button
- Upon clicking the clear button, the blur function is called again and a fresh result pulled by AJAX flashes up again a second time.

How can I avoid a conflict between the clear button and blur function ?

```
<div id="CheckerDiv">ID:
    <input type="text" id="CheckerID" />
</div>
<div id="CheckerClearDiv" style="display:none">
    <a href="" id="CheckerClearDivButton"></a>
</div>
<div id="CheckerResult"></div>

    (function (checkweb, $, undefined) {
    checkweb.Checker = function (vNumber) {
        console.log('ajax fired');
        var msgBox = $("#CheckerResult");
        var checkerDiv = $("#CheckerDiv");
        var checkerClearDiv = $("#CheckerClearDiv");
        // do stuff here that returns an ajax
        msgBox.html('AJAX RETURN !');
        checkerDiv.hide();
        checkerClearDiv.show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            msgBox.text('');
        }, 15000);
    };
}(window.checkweb = window.checkweb || {}, jQuery));

$(document).ready(function () {
    // ID checker
    $('#CheckerDiv').on("blur", '#CheckerID', function (e) {
        var n = $('#CheckerID').val();
        if (n.length > 10) {
            console.log('blur fired');
            checkweb.Checker(n);
        }
        $('#CheckerID').val('');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#CheckerResult").text('');
        }, 5000);
    });
    $('#CheckerDiv').on("keyup change", '#CheckerID', function (e) {
        var n = $(this).val();
        if (n.length > 10) {
            console.log('change fired');
            checkweb.Checker(n);
        }
    });
    $('#CheckerClearDivButton').on("click", function () {
        console.log('button fired');
        $('#CheckerID').val('');
        $("#CheckerResult").text('');
        $("#CheckerClearDiv").hide();
        $("#CheckerDiv").show();
    });
    //
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "return false"; as last statement in your clear function.

```
$('#CheckerClearDivButton').on("click", function () {
        console.log('button fired');
        $('#CheckerID').val('');
        $("#CheckerResult").text('');
        $("#CheckerClearDiv").hide();
        $("#CheckerDiv").show();
        return false; //<----
    });
```

Comment: Have just tried this, unfortunately the same occurs.

Comment: I adjusted your jsFiddle and it appears to be doing what you want to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/k1g3upbv/1/

Comment: The return false was the only thing you added, right ?  Hmm.... looks like I need to go back and double check I applied the change first time round !

Comment: The only thing I added beside that was the text "Clear Button", to visualize the link

Comment: Ok, well, although it still doesn't work for me on my live code. But the JSFiddle certainly seems to do what you say it does,so I'll award you the answer and guess I'll just spend some time on my own bashing my head against my own code !

Comment: Tanks, and success with the outcome.

Comment: Keep in mind that your code as shown doesn't wait for the ajax response to complete. So the line    msgBox.html('AJAX RETURN !') and further will probably be executed even before your ajax response is received. Have you tried to put the code after your rajax request in the ".success" propertie op your call?

Comment: Interesting thought Steven, didn't think the problem might be the Ajax delay ! Will try it out...

Comment: For anyone reading this, it seems there might be some sort of bug in Safari  8.0.2.   I've managed to stop the over-firing in Firefox, but Safari still does it.... weird....